# Magento: catalog in /catalog url path

Tags: magento, store, catalog

I hav a navigation with cms pages and a button 'catalog'. This one links to *www.website.nl/catalog*

I want to display the catagories under this url.
I tried to rename the root categorie to 'catalog' and show the root category in the navigation, but that isn't possible ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/creating_and_assigning_root_categories )

Now I have 'catalog' as a cms-page with a static block wich shows the categories. It works, but when the visitor clicks a categorie, the breadcrumbs don't show 'catalog' anymore. Just: 'Home -> Category name'.

And the url is *www.website.nl/categorypath* and not *www.website.nl/catalog/categorypath*.

Is it possible to setup the store like this?

I hope I explained my problem clearly enough.

Greets Niek

Answer (score 1):

Move your categories to a subcategory of root called "Catalog", then reindex.

You can display products in a grid on your homepage with the following shortcode in the content area of the cms editor (or layout updates with slightly different syntax which you should know if you are messing with layout updates):

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Where 4 in category_id="4" would be replaced with your "Catalog" subcategory's ID

Comment: Yeah I think this is the best solution. But I want to know if there is a solution for displaying the root categorie. So I don't want to put all the categories in a subcategory.

Comment: I don't think Magento was designed to be set up that way... good luck with however it goes though!