# In Magento, how do you add the catalog to a page link?

Tags: xml, magento, layout, content-management-system, catalog

I've made a custom page.xml layout and it is working.  Now, how do I add the catalog to the link entitled "products" in the header?  Right now it is a CMS page.

You can see site so far [here](http://prodetailcarcare.evermight.com/home):

I've been searching all afternoon, and couldn't find anything.  The closest was this, but it wouldn't work either after trying a few variations.
[Magento: catalog in /catalog url path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992365/magento-catalog-in-catalog-url-path)

In the custom theme, I have copied and created the folders for layout/catalog.xml, catalog/navigation/left.phtml, catalog/category/view/phtml and catalog/product/gallery.phtml.

Comment: It depends on what do you call "catalog".

Comment: for the `catalog in /catalog url path`, you need to elaborate on "it wouldn't work".  please explain the results... is it 404? a redirect? you're seing some other page?

Comment: are you sure your inventory is not zero or you disabled your products in anyway?

Comment: @Tim By "catalog" I mean all the dynamic product content.  Categories and product listings.

Comment: @John I probed further into the errors I was getting with the link in my post and found some settings for when products should be displayed.  I changed these settings and I have some product showing now.  I'll re-post once I know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, instead of making the link a CMS page, I simply pointed it to a catalog's category.

I created a sub-category called "products" inside the default top-level category, which I found out is good practice to keep the breadcrumbs in tact.  Created the URL slug "products".  Then pointed the link to www.magentostore/products.  Initially that didn't work, but after investigating further, I needed to add .html to the end so it should be  www.magentostore/products.html.  Products showed up after that.

Also, as John says in the comments, make sure that the settings for displaying products and inventory levels are set in the sites's admin (System, Config, Catalog/Inventory).